# Play HTTP live streaming using m3u8 file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have to play live streaming video using m3u8 file
I know it is possible using this code:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:requiredTubeUrl];
MoviePlayerController *myMovie = [[MoviePlayerController alloc]init];
[myMovie initAndPlayMovie:movieURL];
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
{
       MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
       if (mp)
       {
           [self.moviePlayer play];
       }
}
```

But what should I do when my m3u8 url should addresses another index files of m3u8 url like this:
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

which will address another index.m3u8 file so it will be not play directly so what to do next?

Thanx in advance..